# C# Scroll ListView to Updated Item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListView`

```
    <ListView x:Name="BlockList" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="75" Header="Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Address, Converter={StaticResource IntToHexConverter}}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Length" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Length}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

showing the Address, Length, and Status of an `ObservableCollection` of `Blocks`.

```
public class Block : ObservableObject
{
    public enum BlockStatus
    {
        Unwritten,
        Written,
        Verified,
        Bad,
    }

    private UInt16 address;
    public UInt16 Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private byte[] data;
    public byte[] Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private BlockStatus status;
    public BlockStatus Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set { status = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public UInt16 Length
    {
        get { return (UInt16)Data.Length; }
    }

    public Block(UInt16 address, byte[] data) : this(address, data, BlockStatus.Unwritten) { }

    public Block(UInt16 address, byte[] data, BlockStatus status)
    {
        this.Address = address;
        this.Data = data;
        this.Status = status;
    }
}
```

These `Blocks` will initially start in the `BlockStatus.Unwritten` state, eventually be `Written`, then be `Verified`. How can I scroll my `ListView` to a `Block` when it's `Status` changes?

[image: Example Window]

Comment: That sounds like a bit of an ugly solution. Bad UX. The user should be free to scroll without interruption I would suggest having a status bar where the latest status update is shown. Or only add items to the ListBox once they are written and scroll to bottom each time new item is added.

Comment: Glen it's not for you to decide what's bad UX for his project. It's perfectly reasonable to auto-scroll a list item into view.

Answer (score 0):

There a bunch of things that need to be done.

1) Your `Block` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class Block : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Your existing members and code


    private BlockStatus _status;
    public BlockStatus Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set { _status = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Status"); }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

2) Your `ViewModel` needs to have a `StatusChanged` event

```
public delegate void StatusChangedHandler(object sender, StatusChangedHandlerArgs args);
public event StatusChangedHandler StatusChanged;

// Put this class where it suits your project
public class StatusChangedHandlerArgs
{
    public Block.BlockStatus NewStatus { get; private set; }

    public StatusChangedHandlerArgs(Block.BlockStatus newStatus)
    {
        NewStatus = newStatus;
    }
}
```

3) The `Blocks` property in your `ViewModel` needs to look like this:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Block> _blocks;
    public ObservableCollection<Block> Blocks
    {
        get
        {
            return _blocks;
        }
        set
        {
            _blocks = value;
            if (_blocks != null)
            {
                foreach (var block in _blocks)
                {
                    block.PropertyChanged += block_PropertyChanged;
                }
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Blocks");
        }
    }

   // The event handler for PropertyChanged 
    private void block_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName != "Status" || StatusChanged == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var block = sender as Block;
        if (block != null)
        {
            StatusChanged.Invoke(block, new StatusChangedHandlerArgs(block.Status));
        }
    }
```

4) Finally your `View` (which has an instance of the `ViewModel`) should subscribe to the `StatusChanged` event in the code behind.

```
   // Somewhere in the initializer or constructor for the page
   yourViewModel.StatusChanged += yourViewModel_StatusChanged;

   // The handler for StatusChanged
   private void yourViewModel_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedHandlerArgs args)
    {
        var block = sender as Block;
        if (block != null)
        {
            BlockList.ScrollIntoView(block);
        }
    }
```